# Click event in android custom dialog mono for android

Tags: android, dialog, xamarin.android

I created a custom dialog but I don't know how to create onclick events for the imageview within my custom xml layout for the dialog. Here's how I do it.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
            dialog.Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
            dialog.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_pause_menu);
            // Auto size the dialog based on it's contents
            dialog.Window.SetLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            dialog.Show();
```

I can do this in java by using something like this.

```
ImageView btn= (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do something
            }
        });
```

But I don't know how to do this in C#. Again, i'm using mono for android(C# and this is for cutom dialogs) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This superb tutorial about MonoDroid Dialogs should tell you everything you need to know - http://blog.ostebaronen.dk/2013/02/using-dialogs-in-mono-for-android.html

You should be able to do something like:

```
var btn= (ImageView)dialog.FindViewById(Resource.Id.btn);
btn.Click += (s,e) => { /* do something */ };
```

But see that tutorial to learn much much more

http://blog.ostebaronen.dk/2013/02/using-dialogs-in-mono-for-android.html

Comment: I'm getting an error, The non-generic method 'Android.App.Dialog.FindViewById(int)' cannot be used with the type arguments.

Comment: I've read the tutorial but it doesn't cover my problem. I need to add a click event on the imageViews in my custom layout for the dialog.

Comment: if you look at the password example that uses the non-generic form of FindViewById and just casts to EditText

Comment: Ohhhh. Didn't see that. I used the code you posted and didn't notice the ones used in the blog. Thanks!

Comment: Have fixed the code to use non-generic. If more fixes are needed please do edit the answer to correct it :)